# Java Netbeans Login Form

Tags: java, swing, sqlite

I am a beginner in java.For academic purpose I have to develop a system.In that system in the login form there are three field I have to cover:username,password and selecting user level by using jcombobox.As far as I've done with my project is that I can login with any username,password of the database and I link my jcombobox with the database.But I want to login by giving particular username and password which is stored in database and selecting the particular login level (like login as administrator/manager/engineer) from jcombobox.Only that particular person can login with the username,password and level.Another person of another level have to give their required username,password,level.
Here is my code,

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LogInJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

Connection conn=null;
ResultSet rs = null;
PreparedStatement pst=null;

public LogInJFrame() {
    initComponents();
    conn=JavaConnector.ConnectorDb();
    Fill_Combo();
}

private void Fill_Combo()
{
    try
    {
        String sql="Select * from Level";
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs=pst.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
        String type=rs.getString("Type");
        cmb_loginAs.addItem(type);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            rs.close();
            pst.close();

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
} 

private void btn_loginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    String sql="select * from Level where UserName =? and Password =?  ";
try{

pst =conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1, txt_username.getText());
pst.setString(2, txt_password.getText());

rs=pst.executeQuery();

if(rs.next())
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Username and Password is correct");
    rs.close();
    pst.close();

    AdministratorLogin ad=new AdministratorLogin();
    ad.setVisible(true);
}
else
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Username and Password is not correct");
}
}
catch(Exception e)
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
finally
    {
        try
        {
            rs.close();
            pst.close();

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
}                                         

private void txt_passwordKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                        
    if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
    {
        String sql="select * from Level where UserName =? and Password =?  ";
try{

pst =conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1, txt_username.getText());
pst.setString(2, txt_password.getText());

rs=pst.executeQuery();
if(rs.next())
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Username and Password is correct");
    rs.close();
    pst.close();

    AdministratorLogin ad=new AdministratorLogin();
    ad.setVisible(true);
}
else
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Username and Password is not correct");
}
}
catch(Exception e)
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
finally
    {
        try
        {
            rs.close();
            pst.close();

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
    }

    }
}                                                         
}
```

I've tried a lot but can't figure out exactly what I need to do to get my desired result.Will anyone help me with that please?Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always link the username and password to an account type inside of the DB. Then get that out from the DB store it in a string. then do something like

```
if(accountType.equals("engineer")) {
     // load specific page
}
```